# Getting the query plan for statements inside a stored procedure in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, plpgsql

I have a really basic plpgsql stored procedure like this:

```
create or replace procedure new_emp_sp (f_name varchar, l_name varchar, age integer, threshold integer)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    new_emp_count integer;
begin
    INSERT INTO employees (id, first_name, last_name, age)
        VALUES (nextval('emp_id_seq'), 
                random_string(10),
                random_string(20),
                age);
    select count(*) into new_emp_count from employees where age > threshold;
    update dept_employees set emp_count = new_emp_count where id = 'finance';
end; $$
```

After calling this stored procedure using `call`, how do I get the query plans for each of the statements that were executed by the procedure?

Found a couple of StackOverflow answers for a similar requirement but with **functions** instead of procedures using the `auto_explain` module and I followed the below steps but it did not work:

1. Executed `LOAD '$libdir/plugins/auto_explain';` (I am using an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance and found this command in [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html))
2. Executed `SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0;`
3. Executed `SET auto_explain.log_analyze  = true;`
4. Executed `SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = true;`

But after executing the procedure, I did not see any visible changes in the output.

For my current requirement I **cannot** access any log files on the database server and can only run commands on the server through a client / programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have log messages sent to the client:

```
set client_min_messages TO log;
```

This works fine with auto_explain.log_nested_statements (in `psql`, anyway).  I use it all the time to avoid needing to go scrounge through the log file.

Comment: It works! Is this the only way of getting the query plan for a stored procedure/function?

Comment: Its the only way I know of.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the only way of getting the query plan for a stored procedure/function?

There is a way without installing `auto_explain`. The [**`EXPLAIN`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) command returns a set of `text`, and you can work with that in a PL/pgSQL code block.

#### In a [**`FUNCTION`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) or [**`PROCEDURE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)

- [When to use stored procedure / user-defined function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684)

Showing a **temporary procedure**, which is only visible inside your session. See:

- [How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990622/how-to-create-a-temporary-function-in-postgresql/31095452#31095452)

```sql
-- create once:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pg_temp.get_plan ()
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
DECLARE
   _line text;
BEGIN
   FOR _line IN
      EXPLAIN ANALYZE
      SELECT 1         -- your query here !!!
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _line;
   END LOOP;
END
$proc$;

-- call:
CALL pg_temp.get_plan();
```

You'll get in your client - for any client that shows notices, and with [`client_min_messages`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES) at `NOTICE` or lower:

```
NOTICE:  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
NOTICE:  Planning Time: 0.045 ms
NOTICE:  Execution Time: 0.035 ms
CALL
```

#### In a [**`DO`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) command

To execute an anonymous code block without creating any objects:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _line text;
BEGIN
   FOR _line IN
      EXPLAIN ANALYZE  -- more options?
      SELECT 1         -- your query here !!!
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _line;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

See:

- [EXPLAIN ANALYZE within PL/pgSQL gives error: "query has no destination for result data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101229/explain-analyze-within-pl-pgsql-gives-error-query-has-no-destination-for-resul)
- [Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/23355/3684)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does work only issue for me with your approach is that a new procedure will need to be created and that does not fit my current use case. No issue other than that basically. Hope it will help someone else. Thanks again!

Comment: @user9492428: For the record, you can also execute an anonymous code block without  creating any objects. I added a bit above.